# Logging into a website using Goutte over HTTPS

Tags: php, https, wamp, guzzle, goutte

I'm trying to use goutte and wamp on windows 10 to login to a website but I'm getting the following error.

```
RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I'm getting the error even using the example code provided.

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://github.com/');
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('login' => 'fabpot', 'password' => 'xxxxxx'));
$crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```